# Calling a function overloaded in several namespaces from inside one namespace

Tags: c++, overloading

I have the following code snippet:

```
void foo(double a) {}

namespace bar_space
{
  struct Bar {};

  void foo(Bar a) {}
}
```

foo(double) is a general function from a library.
I have my own namespace bar_space with my own struct, Bar. I would like to implement an overloading of foo() for Bar, thus making Bar more similar to the built-in types.

Trouble appears when I attempt to call the original foo(double) from within the namespace:

```
namespace bar_space
{
  void baz()
  {
    foo(5.0); // error: conversion from ‘double’ to non-scalar type ‘ssc::bar_space::Bar’ requested
  }
}
```

This fails to compile on gcc on both my Fedora and Mac.

Calling

```
foo(5.0)
```

from outside the namespace or using

```
namespace bar_space
{
  ::foo(5.0)
}
```

works ok, but this doesnt make my new function quite as nice as I had hoped for (other developers are also working inside bar_space).

Is bar_space hiding the original function? Is there a way to make foo(5.0) callable from within bar_space without explicit scoping (::)? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm a newbie at C++, but can you use something like `using bar_space::foo;`?

Comment: That will help using foo(Bar) outside bar_space, but not getting foo(double) into bar_space.

Comment: something similiar is possible: http://codepad.org/0IcNXZb6

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In C++, there is a concept called [*name hiding*](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fname_hiding.htm).  Basically, a function or class name is "hidden" if there is a function/class of the same name in a nested scope.  This prevents the compiler from "seeing" the hidden name.

Section 3.3.7 of the C++ standard reads:

> A name can be hidden by an explicit
>   declaration of that same name in a
>   nested declarative region or derived
>   class (10.2)

So, to answer your question: in your example `void foo(double a);` is *hidden* by `void bar_space::foo(Bar a);`  So you need to use the `::` scoping operator to invoke the outer function.

Comment: there's no bar_space::foo(double)

Comment: The standard has spoken, then. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: The one piece missing here is that _name-mangling_ is applied **after** _name-hiding_.  If it were the other way around, that code would have worked as (incorrectly) expected.

Answer (score 4):

However, in your sample code you could use something like that

```
namespace bar_space 
{
    using ::foo;
    void baz()
    {
       Bar bar;
       foo(5.0);
       foo(bar);
    }
}
```

Comment: I was going to post this answer and just tested it and it compiled fine for me. (I also got distracted by meetings at work, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, bar_space is hiding the original function and no, you can't make foo(5.0) callable from whithin bar_space without explicit scoping **if** foo(double) is defined in the global namespace.

Comment: Well well, I will use the :: then. I didn't mention it, but foo() is really the function ceil() from math.h, so it is defined in the global namespace.

Comment: @Christian - if you include `<cmath>` instead (which you should be doing anyway), then `ceil` will be included in the `std` namespace, in which case your problem will go away.

Comment: I just did. Problem went away. And yes, I should have used <cmath> all the way...