# ostream operator << in Namespace hides other ostream::operator

Tags: c++, g++, operator-overloading, language-lawyer, ostream

Using gcc version 5.2.0 (GCC) with --std=c++14, the following code does not compile anymore, if the commented out operator ostream in namespace MyNamespace is uncommented. Is this a bug or a feature? (Compile with g++ -c --std=c++14 x.cxx)

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

typedef std::pair<std::string, std::string> StringPair;

std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream&, const StringPair &pair) {
  std::cout <<pair.first<<"."<<pair.second;
}

namespace MyNamespace {
  class MyClass {};
  //std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream&, const MyClass &);
  void xxx ();
}

void MyNamespace::xxx () {
  StringPair pair;pair.first="1";pair.second="2";
  std::cout <<pair<<std::endl;
}
```

The error-message i get with the operator << uncommented is:

```
x.cxx: In function ‘void MyNamespace::xxx()’:
x.cxx:18:13: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ and ‘StringPair {aka std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >}’)
std::cout <<pair<<std::endl;
         ^
```

Comment: First you should probably remove the *undefined behavior* in your code, you need to return something from the global `operator<<` function taking the pair. And you should probably use the stream being passed as argument instead of hard-coding `std::cout`. Doesn't solve your problem, but unrelated problems tend to hide the actual problems.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I just tried and reproduced the reported error. I don't think the undefined behavior can have anything to do with it - this happens during compilation

Comment: Its not about running the code. It's about compiling it. Of course this behaviour makes no sense, but that's what I get :-)

Comment: Link to ideone reproducing the bahavior: https://ideone.com/Lgg5oL

Comment: @pbhd I made it compile by adding `using ::operator<<` to the namespace. But I'm not sure why it's required. You can check https://ideone.com/01ypI9

Comment: This has to be a problem with [ADL](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) but I just can't see why. Note that VS2017 also have this problem, not limited to GCC.

Comment: Also not limited to GCC with std=c++14. I don't know what is going on either

Comment: @MichaelNastenko I think this is an example of [name hiding](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.cbclx01/name_hiding.htm)

Comment: @JHBonarius Ok, I see. And standard operators not hidden because of they declared in stream class itself?

Comment: As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11359733/6717178) "this feature doesn't interfere with Koenig lookup[...], so IO operators from `std::` will still be found."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438281/calling-a-function-overloaded-in-several-namespaces-from-inside-one-namespace), this is an example of [name hiding](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.cbclx01/name_hiding.htm). By defining `operator<<` in namespace `MyNamespace` all the definitions from the higher namespaces (like global) are hidden.

Note that as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11359733/6717178):

> [...]this feature doesn't interfere with Koenig lookup [...], so IO operators from `std::` will still be found.

([details about Koenig lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl))

The solution is to refer to the overload in the other namespace with the `using` directive, as described [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/was37tzw.aspx). This was mentioned in the comments by Michael Nastenko.

Thus `using ::operator<<;`, with `::` referring to the global namespace.

Thus the code will become:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

typedef std::pair<std::string, std::string> StringPair;

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const StringPair &pair) {
    os << pair.first << '.' << pair.second;
    return os;
}

namespace MyNamespace {
    class MyClass {};
    using ::operator<<;
    std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream&, const MyClass &);
    void xxx();
}

void MyNamespace::xxx() {
    StringPair pair("1","2");
    std::cout<<pair<<std::endl;
}

int main() {
    MyNamespace::xxx();
    return 0;
}
```

[example on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1283901e500bfdac)